# Input no Selenium com Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Comecei a estudar a ferramenta `selenium` há exatas 2 horas e queria saber se é possível fazer o seguinte:
Executar um programa e ele me perguntar o site que quero acessar, colar o link e o programa abrir o site no link que digitei, é possível?

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim, para começar lembre-se de baixar, **de acordo com a versão do navegador**, o [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) caso esteja usando o navegador `Google Chrome` ou o [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.29.1) caso esteja usando o navegador `Firefox`, e deixar o executável **no mesmo caminho que seu arquivo de execução**.

Inicie seu código importando o módulo `selenium`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
```

Para definir qual site você irá abrir, crie uma vaiável que receberá um `input`:

```py
url = str(input('Site: '))
```

Feito isso, crie a variável `driver` que receberá o navegador:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Por fim, adicione o método `.get()` na variável `driver` colocando a variável `url` como parâmetro para acessar o site:

```py
driver.get(url)
```

O código completo fica assim:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

url = str(input('Site: '))
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```

Para saber mais sobre o módulo `Selenium`, [Clique aqui](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage)